# A nice combinatorics problem: show that John can implement his painting idea in at most $n/2$ years.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So, here is the problem:

There are $n$ squares in the city that are connected to $n-1$ streets. One street connects exactly two squares, and from each square it is possible to reach every other in a unique way. In the beginning, the pavements of all streets were painted either red or blue.
John became the deputy mayor of that city, and he wants to implement his idea about painting the sidewalk. The idea is his own, it means it is any pattern of colours, not nessicarily a specific design (there are $2^{n-1}$ ways to colour the city, and the idea can be any of those patterns) However, in order for the citizens not to experience the change too suddenly, every year John chooses one square and changes the color of all the streets leading to that square (red pavements are painted blue and vice versa).
Show that regardless of the way the squares are connected and how the pavements are initially painted, John can implement his painting idea in at most $n/2$ years.

My friend gave me this problem, he says it is from some online competition, but unfortunately, he didn't tell me the name of the competition. I think it is a very nice problem, so I tried with a couple of small cases: If $n=2$, then it is pretty straightforward that it can be done. If $n=3$, the streets can be arranged in a triangle, but then there would be $n$ streets, and not $n-1$, so, they must be arranged in a line.
Again, continuing with that logic, It is pretty obvious that there can never be a loop of squares, aka. there can never be $k$ squares connected with $k$ streets, because there wouldn't be a unique path anymore, you could go counterclockwise or clockwise. From that point on I am not sure what to do, I don't know if what I said so far is even correct. To be honest, I feel like this could be done with induction, but I just don't know how to start with it, so that's where I have become stuck...

Hey, I just edited the problem, my friend just told me that it is any coloring, not a specific design. It is relatively easy to prove that it would take the longest if he was to change every colour, so the solutions are still valid.

Comment: Hint:  It's clear, I think, that the optimal number increases by at most $1$ each time. That means you only need to argue that half the time it doesn't go up at all.

Comment: Is it something like induction?

Comment: Post edit:  I would add that to the problem statement.  It seems critical....why leave it to a postscript?

Comment: Like to prove it for even $n$, and then continue the argument for odd?

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll fix it

Comment: I would expect the parity of $n$ to be relevant, yes.

Comment: No no I just clicked it on accident. I'm sorry for my mistake, I didn't mean to click it. Sorry.

Comment: No worries.  Should say:  I haven't thought through the parity issue.  The idea, I expect, will be to show that you can always make the right choices if the parity is suitable.

Comment: To check, is the goal simply to paint each of the sidewalks (in which case the color of red/blue seems redundant), or to get the sidewalks to be of the same color (which was my initial, wrong interpretation)

Comment: In other words, show that every [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) with $n$ vertices has a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) of size at most $n/2$.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem you can think of the city as a graph. It is well known, that a connected graph, where there is only one unique path between any two of its vertices, is a tree. Any tree is bipartite graph, meaning you can devide its vertices into 2 parts, so that no 2 vertices from the same part are adjacent. This means, that if the mayor will choose squares from only one of those parts every time, no streets will be repainted twice. On the other hand, every street will be painted at least once, as every edge connects to a vertex from each part. Finally, observe that one of these 2 parts contains no more than $\dfrac n 2$ squares.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

We represent the city by a graph. We connect two squares (vertices) by an edge if and only if there is a direct road between them, and that road is unpainted. At first, the graph is connected. As we paint roads, we will remove (disconnect) that edge.

Proceed by induction:

As has been mentioned in the other answer, the city (at the start) represents a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

Here's an outline of the inductive step:
Since the graph has at least two leaves, consider one leaf $V$. $V$ is connected to exactly one other vertice $U$. Select vertice $U$, and remove (paint) all the edges from $U$. Then you will get $r$ (unpainted) trees which have no. of vertices $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_r$ and no. of edges $x_1-1,x_2-1, \ldots, x_r-1$, where $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_r = n-2$. By assumption, they can be painted in at most $(n-2)/2$ years.

By $r$ unpainted trees in the above paragraph, I only mean that the graph (which was connected earlier and was a tree) has broken into several ($r$) connected components, each of which is a tree. Now, you can use the induction hypotheses on these $r$ trees.

Comment: What do you mean we get r unpainted trees? Where did they come from?

Comment: @Kokos Hang on, I'll edit the answer to make it clearer