# A nice combinatorics problem: correction

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I know I already posted this problem, but I wanted to give you the correct problem, because the one I posted before wasn't explained correctly (it's my bad, the solutions for the invorrect problem are correct). So, to end the discussion, here is the correct problem (background story and further information explained in the post I posted before this):

There are $n$ squares in the city that are connected to $n-1$ streets. One street connects exactly two squares, and from each square it is possible to reach every other in a unique way. At the beginning, the pavements of all streets were painted either red or blue.

Borna became the deputy mayor of that city, and he wants to implement his idea about painting the sidewalks (which is some arbitrary painting). However, so that the citizens do not experience the change too suddenly, every year Borna chooses one square and changes the color of all the streets DIRECTLY leading to that square, it means if square $A$ is connected to squares $B$ and $C$, then lines $AB$ and $AC$ lead DIRECTLY to the square $A$(red pavements are painted blue and vice versa).

Show that regardless of the way the squares are connected and how the pavements are initially painted, Borna can implement his painting idea (whatever it may be) in at most $n/2$ years.

So this is the problem. I mistakenly suggested that the problem requires the get the "opposite" coloring, turns out it can be any arbitrary coloring. To find the progress we made (or inspiration) check out the problem I posted before this:
[A nice combinatorics problem: show that John can implement his painting idea in at most $n/2$ years.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857887/a-nice-combinatorics-problem-show-that-john-can-implement-his-painting-idea-in)

Comment: If the problem is connected to a previous one you shall give a link to this previous problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: I do not understand this problem. We don't have to change all blue to red, and all red to blue?

Comment: It bothers me that you say that the problem is from "some online competition" but don't say which one, or whether it is ongoing. The problem is a nice one and I'd be happy to post a solution, but I don't want to enable cheating.

Comment: The round this problem was in is over, I just checked it myself. All the solutions are NO longer being accepted. If you also want to check, it is from "MONOM", it is a Croatian math competition. If you want to visit the site, here it is:https://www.skoljka.org/monom23/scoreboard/

Comment: Sorry I didn't state the origin before, thanks for the suggestion